# Elements floating around the form container

Tags: vb.net-2010

I've set my main form as a container but whenever i open a child form, the buttons inside the container stays on top. How can i get around with this? Thank you so much! I've attached a snip shot of my problem. Thank you again.

http://s26.postimg.org/7l3mdyli1/image.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use Panel from toolbox and populate the Panel with your controls/buttons.
The good thing about panel is, the x,y of your button controls within panel will be relative to the panel (e.g the 0,0 of your button left,top will be always be on the left top of your panel) this has significant advantage for positioning, rather than calculating the position of a button using your form coordinate.

Hope this help.